# How to configure sub-domain for images on Debian Apache VPS?

Tags: images, subdomains, apache, cdn, vps

in shorts: I want this https://surpriseazwebservices.com/serve-images-from-sub-domain-in-wordpress/
BUT, I have VPS with Debian runing Apache and WP. I follow all steps from tutorial and not working for me. I was reading little (I mean - a lot) on Google and find something like "VirtualServers". 
I didn't understand clearly, but I think I have to configure Apache for new sub-domain, or something.
Can someone write full tutorial how to make this?
So, VPS, Debian, Apache, WP, Sub-domain for images (like self-cdn).

P.S I want to keep all images in their primary directory (like in tutorial: public_html/wp-content/uploads).